# Line breaking and alignment in list

Tags: lists, line-breaking

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  12pt
]{article}


\usepackage[
  hmargin=2.4cm,
  vmargin=3cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate} % better to use enumitem
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage[
  colorlinks=true,
  urlcolor=black
]{hyperref}


\newcommand*\ops[1]{\textbf{\textsf{#1}}}
\newcommand*\options[3]{\color{#1}\ops{#2}\fontsize{#3}{#3}}
\newcommand*\film[4]{%
 \item \fontsize{12pt}{12pt} \selectfont \textsf{[#4] \enskip \href{#1}{#2}~(#3)}}
\setlength{\labelsep}{0em}
\renewcommand*\labelenumi{\options{blue}{\ops}{10pt} $\maltese$ \quad}

\regtotcounter{enumi}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \film{http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0134273/}{8MM}{1999}{6,4}
  \film{http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050083/}{12 Angry Men}{1957}{8,9}
  \item\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont \textsf{[2,1] \enskip \href{http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0057181/}{Incredibly Strange Creatures Who Stopped Living and Became Mixed-Up}}\\ \verb++\hspace{9.9mm} \textsf{{\href{http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0057181/}{Zombies, The}} (2006)}
\end{enumerate}

\noindent I have \total{enumi}~films.

\end{document}
```

How do I get automatically line breaking if a title is too long *and* left alignment of the title (as I have done manually for the last item) if it spans more than one line?

**Follow-up question**

Consider David's code:

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  12pt
]{article}


\usepackage[
  hmargin=2.4cm,
  vmargin=3cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage[
  colorlinks=true,
  urlcolor=black
]{hyperref}


\newcommand*\film[4]{%
  \item[\refstepcounter{enumi}\textcolor{blue}{$\maltese$}\quad\textsf{[#4]}] \textsf{\href{#1}{#2}~(#3)}}


\regtotcounter{enumi}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[
  leftmargin=5em,
  labelindent=-5em
]
  \film{http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0134273/}{8MM}{1999}{6,4}
  \film{http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050083/}{12 Angry Men}{1957}{8,9}
  \film{http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0057181/}{Incredibly Strange Creatures Who Stopped Living and Became Mixed-Up Zombies, The}{2006}{2,1}
\end{enumerate}

\noindent I have \total{enumi}~films.

\end{document}
```

What options do I have to give to `enumerate` in order to get the same alignment as in my initial code?

The problem is that with David's approach, there is too little space between the symbol and [x,y], and between [x,y] and the title. If I try to add some space, the symbol goes into the left margin.

**Update 2**

One last question: I would like an `\if` loop; something like

```
\if \total{enumi} = 1
  I have 1~film.
 \else
  I have \total{enumi}~films.
\fi
```

but it doesn't work. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `\fontsize` you need to follow it with `\selectfont` and its dangerous to use the same length in both arguments as usually it will lead to inconsistent line spacing.

[image]

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  12pt
]{article}


\usepackage[
  hmargin=2.4cm,
  vmargin=3cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem} % better to use enumitem
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage[
  colorlinks=true,
  urlcolor=black
]{hyperref}



\newcommand*\film[4]{%
 \item[\refstepcounter{enumi}\textcolor{blue}{$\maltese$} \textsf{[#4]}] \textsf{\href{#1}{#2}~(#3)}}


\regtotcounter{enumi}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=5em,labelindent=-5em]
  \film{http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0134273/}{8MM}{1999}{6,4}
  \film{http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050083/}{12 Angry Men}{1957}{8,9}
\film{http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0057181/}{Incredibly Strange Creatures Who Stopped Living and Became Mixed-Up Zombies, The}{2006}{2,1}
\end{enumerate}

I have \total{enumi}~films.

\end{document}
```

or more spaced out

[image]

```
\newcommand*\film[4]{%
 \item[\refstepcounter{enumi}\textcolor{blue}{$\maltese$}\hspace{2em}\textsf{[#4]}] \textsf{\href{#1}{#2}~(#3)}}

..

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=15em,labelindent=-10em,align=left,labelwidth=10em]
```

Comment: I have a follow-up question; please see my updated question.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg 2nd example added

Comment: Perfect, David!

Comment: I have one last, extra question, David; see updated question.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg you should ask new questions in a new question, but `\if \total{enumi}` tests if the first two non expandable tokens in the expansion of `\total` are the same. You meant to  use `ifnum` but again that only works if \total{enumi} expands to a number which it certainly doesn't the first time. As you don't need back reference you don't need the totcount stuff and can just use `\ifnum\value{enumi}=1 ...`

Comment: Sorry, David; I'll remember that for the next time. Thank you for helping anyway.